# Can't Use Default Mail Client. Am I Missing Something?

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

I'm having trouble with elementary OS' default email client where I can't even log in even after I carefully typed my email and password there. Am I missing something here? I already tried adding my email through the Online Accounts section in settings, which it did but still didn't even log me in the default email client. Maybe I need to change some settings? If that's the case then, you guys know what to do.

Another weird problem is that I can't remove my account in the Online Accounts section. Even if I click that little minus sign below and exit settings, when I go back it's still there.

Comment: try less secure apps in gmail, this page guide you:
<strike>https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account<strike>

Comment: Hello. I've deleted the pictures because it contains personal information. I advise you to delete the pictures on imgur to avoid spam or any other issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your gmail account have *2 step verification* enabled?

Have you enabled *Less secure app access*?

Have you checked that you are using correct keyboard and not using CAPS?

Alternatively you can try gnome online accounts with gnome settings:

```
sudo apt-get update

# Install Gnome Control Center by typing the following command:

sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

# Install Gnome Online Account by typing the following command (optional):

sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts

# Open Gnome Control Center by typing the following command:

Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center –overview
```

---

*accept as answer if it worked for you*

Comment: Enabling less secure app access to my account worked like a charm. Thanks!