# Failure To Connect To Online Accounts, Elementary OS 6

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-odin

When I try to connect either my gmail or my school office365 accounts I get the message:
"IMAP verification failed: You must be working online to complete this operation" so it completely fails to connect.

I have confirmed I have wifi and ethernet access working. I am signed into my accounts on my browser. This error does not occur with my personal outlook email.

I can connect to both of these accounts without issue in Evolution app, but I would much rather use the Elementary OS mail app and calendar. I thought the mail app in Elementary OS 6 uses the same method as evolution -- so if Evolution can connect, what is causing the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Found almost complete work-around is to install evolution through apt-get instead of flatpak -- I can add my accounts through that and it shows up in mail.

If you do it through the flatpak evolution, this does not work. Also, unified inbox still fails -- for example, my office365 inbox account is not included in the unified inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I've enabled IMAP on Gmail configs and enabled *Less secure apps access* as suggested here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/25736/28087

It's working now

Edit:

For use Google Workspace Gmail Account, i've had to uncheck the "Use IMAP Credentials option" and put the credentials of email again

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer support for this kind of authentication.

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

> Important: This deadline does not apply to Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity customers. The enforcement date for these customers will be announced on the Workspace blog at a later date.

[reference](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)